# how do I set headers programmatically on Laravel Http Client?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add some headers but can't find it on the docs

```php
$httpRequest = Http::baseUrl(config('api_base_url'))
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            ]);

// can i do something like this?
if ($var === 'me') {
   $httpRequest->pushToExistingHeaders([
       "Content-Type" => 'multipart/form-data'
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withHeaders` again to merge your headers conditionally with the previous headers as shown in the [`Laravel code`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e5b8538926f29339b44c9c633dab14f996de3a2b/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L369). This is because it adds to the previous headers and doesn't replace them.

This is how other methods like [`accept`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e5b8538926f29339b44c9c633dab14f996de3a2b/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L358), [`content-type`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e5b8538926f29339b44c9c633dab14f996de3a2b/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L337) are accomplishing this.

```
<?php

$httpRequest = Http::baseUrl(config('api_base_url'))
               ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
               ]);


if ($var === 'me') {
   $httpRequest->withHeaders([
       "Content-Type" => 'multipart/form-data'
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make header content as array variable. For example

```
if($var === "me") {
     $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        "Content-Type" => 'multipart/form-data'
     ];
} else {
     $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken
     ];
}


$httpRequest = Http::baseUrl(config('api_base_url'))
->withHeaders($headers);
```